# Repeating button presses

Tags: arduino

I tried to make a Serial keyboard type thing, and I got it to work to be where When You pressed a button, It would display the character on the serial monitor. I had the idea to make a "Shift Function" where it would act like a regular shift on a keyboard but it would instead of making the characters Capital, it would do the next letter (So one button would be "a" but if you pressed the "shift button" and the "a" button it would change the output to a "b" instead of a. Whenever I did this it would just continue to repeat the letter "b" on the serial monitor, even without anything being plugged in. I tested the code on different Boards but They all had the same problem. Its the code for sure but I checked the code multiple times and I didn't think I saw anything wrong.

```
#define button 2
#define button2 3
#define button3 4
#define shiftButton 3

void setup() {
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(shiftButton, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  // Read the digital pin to check status of button
  int pressed = digitalRead(button);
  int pressed2 = digitalRead(button2);
  int pressed3 = digitalRead(button3);
  int shiftKeys = digitalRead(shiftButton);

  // Button returns HIGH if pressed, LOW if not
  if(pressed == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("a");
    delay(450);
  }
  if (shiftKeys == HIGH && pressed == HIGH); {
    Serial.println("b");
    delay(450);
  }

  if(pressed3 == HIGH) {
    Serial.println("c");
    delay(450);
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated
-Thanks!

Comment: Haven't used an arduino, etc in a while. Use the Pins D2-D12 (5-15) instead of 2,3,4 .You could use interrupts. and have a state var. see example code: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/

Comment: Also, ´button2´ and ´shiftButton´ both use pin 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the ; from the line:

```
if(shiftKeys == HIGH && pressed == HIGH); {
```

**Also as a sidenote**: you should use an "else if" for the line `if (shiftKeys == HIGH && pressed == HIGH);`

Otherwise both if statements may return if `pressed == HIGH` and `shiftKeys == HIGH`

Answer (score 0):

`button2` and `shiftButton` both use pin 3:

```
#define button2 3
#define shiftButton 3
```

Also, make sure you are using digital input pins.

In the loop you could do something like this (note: no `;` at the end of the `if` statement):

```
if(pressed == HIGH) {

    if (digitalRead(shiftButton) == HIGH) {
        Serial.println("b");
    }
    else {
        Serial.println("a");
    }

    delay(450);
}
```